# Problemas com a impressão na tela (Linguagem C)

Tags: c, c++

Estou realizando um trabalho onde é pedido isso:

O sistema a ser construído necessitará atender aos requisitos funcionais abaixo:

1 - Possuir a sua identificação (RA-Nome-Curso)
2 - Possuir um menu de opção.
2.1 - Incluir o registro das obras.
2.2 - Listar todos os livros.
2.3 - Listar todas as revistas.
2.4- Listar as obras por caixa.

Porém o meu código está com um problema de na hora da impressão na tela ele "come" a primeira letra e somente ela, por exemplo, digamos que eu queira que seja impresso na tela "Portugal a programar", simplesmente a primeira letra não é impressa e o resto sim ficando "ortugal a programar" sem o P. Isso está ocorrendo em todas as primeiras letras da cada linha. Aqui está meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void menu(){

    printf ("\n\n1 - Cadastrar\n");
    printf ("2 - Listar todos os livros.\n");
    printf ("3 - Listar todas as revistas.\n");
    printf ("4 - Listar as obras por caixa.\n");
    printf ("0 - Sair\n");
}

FILE* AbreArquivo(char modo, char caminho[100]){

    FILE *arquivo;
    switch(modo){

        case 'g':
            arquivo = fopen(caminho,"wt");
            break;
        case 'l':
            arquivo = fopen(caminho,"rt");
            break;
        case 'a':
            arquivo = fopen(caminho,"a");
            break;
    }

    if(arquivo==NULL){

        printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo");
        exit(0);

    }

    return arquivo;
}

void FecharArquivo(FILE *arquivo){

    fclose(arquivo);

}

void Cadastra(char titulo[70],char editora[70], char autor[70], int caixa, int ano, int ISBN){

    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = AbreArquivo('a', "mapa.txt");
    fprintf(arquivo, " \n %s  %s\n  %s\n  \n%d  \n%d  \n%d", titulo, autor, editora, caixa, ano, ISBN);

    FecharArquivo(arquivo);
}

void CadastraRevista(char titulo[70],char editora[70], char autor[70], int caixa, int ano, int ISBN){

    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = AbreArquivo('a', "mapa.txt");
    fprintf(arquivo, " %s; %s; %s; %d %d %d\n", titulo, autor, editora, caixa, ano, ISBN);
    FecharArquivo(arquivo);
}

void Listar(){
    FILE *arquivo;
    char titulo[70];
    char autor[70];
    char editora[70];
    int caixa;
    int ano;
    int ISBN;
    arquivo = AbreArquivo('l',"mapa.txt");
    while(fgets(titulo, 2, arquivo) != NULL){
    fscanf(arquivo," %70[^\n] %70[^\n] %70[^\n] %d %d %d\n", &titulo, &autor, &editora, &caixa, &ano, &ISBN);
        setbuf(stdin,NULL);
        for(int i=0; i<120; i++)printf ("*");
        printf("\nTitulo:  %s -  Autor:  %s  - Editora:  %s  - Caixa:  %d  - Ano:  %d  - ISBN:  %d\n\n", titulo,editora ,autor , caixa, ano, ISBN);

}
    FecharArquivo(arquivo);
}
int main(){

    char titulo[70];
    char autor[100];
    char editora[70];
    int caixa;
    int ano;
    int ISBN;
    int opcao;


    
    menu();
    do{

        printf("\nDigite uma opcao: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        system("cls");

        switch(opcao){
            case 1:

                printf("\nDigite o titulo:  ");
                setbuf(stdin,NULL);
                fgets(titulo, 100, stdin);

                printf("\nDigite o autor:  ");
                setbuf(stdin,NULL);
                fgets(autor,70, stdin);

                printf("\nDigite o editora:  ");
                setbuf(stdin,NULL);
                fgets(editora, 70, stdin);

                printf("\nDigite a caixa:  ");
                scanf("%d", &caixa);

                printf("\nDigite o ano:  ");
                scanf("%d", &ano);

                printf("\nDigite o ISBN:  ");
                scanf("%d", &ISBN);
                Cadastra(titulo, autor, editora, caixa, ano, ISBN);
                system("pause");
                break;

            case 2:
                Listar();
               system("pause");
                break;

            case 3:
                Listar();
                //system("pause");
                break;

            case 4:
                Listar();
               // system("pause");
                break;

            case 0:
                printf("Finalizando......\n");
                system("pause");
                exit(0);

            default:
                printf("\n\nOpcao invalida! Tente Novamente!\n\n");
                system("pause");

        }
    }while(opcao!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tudo indica que é um problema com seu monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bom?

Bem, dei uma olhada aqui no seu código, e não apresentou qualquer erro.

Eu não sei se isso vai ajudar, mais faz assim: no printf, coloca um hifen, ai ele vai comer o hifen e o texto vai continuar.

Também tente reinstalar a sua IDE, pode ser que ajude.

Sei que essa não é uma solução muito boa, mais talvez possa ajudar. Desculpe-me se fui rude, é que só pude pensar nessa solução. Uma boa tarde, noite ou bom dia, dependendo do horário que você estiver vendo isso.